# Get content of last message from a specific channel in Discord using python

Tags: python, discord.py

My question is very specific and i dont know if there is a right answer for it, but what im trying to adchieve is to retrieve a certain value from a message. For instance if the message is:

"Recovered **5** out of **10** messages".


I want to know how i can get both integers from this message in 2 different variables

Edit:
My code at this moment is

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        await self.send_message()
    async def send_message(self):
        channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)
        content = (await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()[0]).content
        await content

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the history method of the channel object.

```
mychannel = client.get_channel(channelID)
content=(await mychannel.history(limit=1).flatten())[0].content
```

From there, you can do whatever you want with content. To extract the numbers, I'd use

```
content=...#see above
a,b=[int(i)for i in content.split()if i.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: im simply just using channel = client.get_channel(*channelID*) to get the channel, but when i try to run your code, i get this error: `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Junior try `content = (await mychannel.history(limit=1).flatten())[0].content` instead. here the [0] is outside the ()

Comment: @WasiMaster That was indeed the solution! thanks in advance to you both for helping me!

Comment: I've added both changes to the answer, so as not to confuse future readers.